# Undefined symbols for _CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer

Tags: ios, audio

I have this code that im trying to use to capture audio data.  However the compiler is complaining about `CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer`

```
    -(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
        AudioBufferList audioBufferList;
        NSMutableData *data= [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
        CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, NULL, &audioBufferList, sizeof(audioBufferList), NULL, NULL, 0, &blockBuffer);

        for (int y = 0; y < audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; y++) {
            AudioBuffer audioBuffer = audioBufferList.mBuffers[y];
            Float32 *frame = (Float32*)audioBuffer.mData;

            [data appendBytes:frame length:audioBuffer.mDataByteSize];
        }
    CFRelease(blockBuffer);
    blockBuffer=NULL;
    [data release];
}
```

error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer", referenced
>   from:
>         -[MicCommunicator captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in
>   MicCommunicator.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: is there a reason why you are appending the frames into a single piece of data? The reason I ask is that I'm using the same function CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer to grab data and send it over a network to be read by an AudioQueue.. but for some reason it's arriving all garbeled and stuff.. and I don't think it's an ABSD formatting issue as I'm using standard lPCM for both the sender and the receiver..

Comment: @www.fossfactory.org yes.  The httpclient I was using for sending took NSData/NSMutableData as an argument.  So it was easiest for me to use that as a container. any time I had garbled audio was because it was using the wrong format (not ulaw).  But my setup was different.

Comment: I know this is kinda of a cop out, but i've spent over a week fiddling with the formatting (and everything else) but no results.. check out the code in this question (do you see anything wrong with the formatting?) i simply use PCM formatting in and out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264799/why-is-audio-coming-up-garbled-when-using-avassetreader-with-audio-queue

Comment: @www.fossfactory.org i will check it out when i have time.  one thing that eventually helped me (worked on this problem for months) was that Apple offers developers support.  You get 2 free with your subscription.  I never knew about the dev support and so i thought maybe you didnt as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linker failing to find a symbol indicates that the library/framework containing that symbol is not listed as a dependency of your build target.  In Xcode, select your target, go to 'Build Phases', open 'Link Binary with Libraries' and add CoreMedia.

Comment: i swear to you i looked for coremedia after seeing this(http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMSampleBuffer/Reference/reference.html) and it wasnt there.  but i looked again after you said this and found it.  so idk wtf happen, but thanks