# Using AudioUnits to play and eq songs from music library

Tags: ios, objective-c, audiounit, avassetreader

I'm building an app that involves playing songs from the user's music library while applying an equalization (EQ) effect.  I've only used `AudioUnits` to generate sound before, so I'm having a bit of trouble.

My current plan is to use `AVAssetReader` to get the samples, and though I'm a bit fuzzy on that, my question here is with regards to the correct `AudioUnit` design pattern to use from Apple's documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/ConstructingAudioUnitApps/ConstructingAudioUnitApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH16-SW1.

My guess is that a render callback is needed to perform my EQ effect (I was thinking `kAudioUnitSubType_ParametricEQ`), so that leaves either the "I/O with a Render Callback Function" pattern or the "Output-Only with a Render Callback Function."  If I'm reading data from the music library (potentially via `AVAssetReader`), which of these two patterns would be the best fit?

Comment: This thread also proved helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264799/why-is-audio-coming-up-garbled-when-using-avassetreader-with-audio-queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to use an Output-Only with a Render Callback Function. The callback function should be responsible for reading/decoding the audio data, and applying the EQ effect.

By the way, I don't know if this might be useful in any way, but [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/UsingSpecificAudioUnits/UsingSpecificAudioUnits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH17-SW4) it says that there's an already existing EQ audio unit that you could use.